# what's the difference phalcon beanstalk queue's choose and watch methods

Tags: php, phalcon, beanstalkd

what's the difference between phalcon beanstalk queue's choose and watch methods.
the comments of the two are same.

```
namespace Phalcon\Queue {
        ...
        /**
         * Change the active tube. By default the tube is 'default'
         *
         * @param string $tube
         * @return string|boolean
         */
        public function choose($tube){ }


        /**
         * Change the active tube. By default the tube is 'default'
         *
         * @param string $tube
         * @return string|boolean
         */
        public function watch($tube){ }
        ...
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"watched" queue is the tube that the client is reserving jobs from.
"used" queue is the tube the client is putting jobs into.

Is it helpful? I think that Phalcon docs here is too short. Should be improved!

Code of Phalcon 2.0:

choose() method:
https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/2.0.0/phalcon/queue/beanstalk.zep#L182

watch() method:
https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/2.0.0/phalcon/queue/beanstalk.zep#L202

Beanstalkd docs fragment:
http://beanstalkc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#tube-management

I always read the code of Phalcon 2.0 because it is written in Zephir which looks like PHP and it is easier to understand than the C code of Phalcon 1.x.x